# getSession next-auth returns null

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am learning NextAuth, and I am just trying to get my current session in an API. Looks pretty easy from the documentation, but it keeps giving me null. If I use useSession from the client-side, I do get the current session though. What am I doing wrong?

```
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';


const handler = nc().use(Cors());

handler.post(async (req, res) => {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        const session = await getSession({ req });
        if (session) {
            console.log('Session', JSON.stringify(session, null, 2));
        } else {
            console.log('Not authenticated.');
            res.status(401);
        }
        res.end();
```

Comment: same issue? any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Took me a lot of time to understand this issue. The solution could be one of the following:

If the next-auth server cannot access the canonical URL defined in the env var `NEXTAUTH_URL` (like `https://example.com` is not reachable from the nextjs server host), another env var must be defined as localhost (mapping to the nextJS server host or docker container): `NEXTAUTH_URL_INTERNAL=http://localhost:<your nextJS host port>`.

---

Check: https://next-auth.js.org/v3/configuration/options#nextauth_url_internal. This var will set next-auth server side actions to execute localhost (it makes sense, since `getServerSideProps()` from nextJS calling `getSession()` for example will invoke a localhost action, doesn't need to route outside)

If setting the internal var doesn't solve, could be due to secure cookies (HTTPS). In `authoptions{}` set `useSecureCookies: false,`: this will tell next-auth to never set the cookies as secure site only (HTTPS)

Comment: I'd like just to highlight that setting `useSecureCookies:false` is a bad idea. `HttpOnly` cookies are there for a reason - to prevent access from JavaScript. It doesn't prevent XSS-attacks, but makes it noticeble more difficult to do so. Have you tried logging `req.cookies` - if it has the session cookie? If not, add the `withCredentials` value to your request.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not able to get session use gettoken instead
In authOption file

```
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET as string,
  callbacks: {
    async signIn(user:any) {
      if (user) {
        const data = await axios.post(`${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/api/sign_in_create_account`, user);
        
        if (data) {
          return user;
        } 
      } else {
        // Return false if login failed
        console.log("Login failed");
        return "/auth/signup";
      }
    },
    
    async jwt({ token, account, profile,user }) {
      // Persist the OAuth access_token and or the user id to the token right after signin
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token
        token.id = user.id
      }
    
      return token;
    },
```

Keys and URL

```
generate your NEXTAUTH_SECRET key from
# Only for production – generate one here: https://generate-secret.vercel.app/32
and Url for local
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

this is api route for calling token

```
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt"
export const GET = async (req) => {
  
  const session = await getToken({ req, secret:process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET })

  return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "GET Property Error", session },
      { status: 200 }
    );
  }
```

and the in your layout/page

```
const MainLayout = ({ children }) => {
  // Data Calling
  const [session, setSession] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetch = async () => {
      if (!session) {
        const response = await axios.get("/api/auth/token");
        if (response.data.session) {
          setSession(true);
        }
      }
    };
    fetch();
  });
return (
    <>
      {session ? (
     // write code when session exist
) : (
     // write code when session is not there
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default MainLayout;
```